How to avoid TransactionTooLargeException in Android?
When the activity is created, it requests the list of installed applications using the following code-
    public static List<PackageInfo> getAppsFromPackageManager(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    return packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
}

I guess this is causing the following exception.

3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.bosch.apps.homescreen, PID: 3852
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 526696 bytes

07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityClient.activityStopped(ActivityClient.java:87)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:143)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 526696 bytes
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:571)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityClientController.java:1315)
07-08 04:35:27.786 1001000  3852  3852 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityClient.activityStopped(ActivityClient.java:84)
Could you please let me know this understanding is right? How to avoid this exception?
